# Access iframe element on the top of another page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dialog, onclick

- I have two jsp pages. 1.customer.jsp 2. menuBanner.jsp
- customer.jsp has an iframe at the top of its contents. that iframe is nothing but menuBanner.jsp file.
- menubanner.jsp has only two contents. an image and a button. on click of the button it has to open a dialog box. the dialog box code should be in menubanner.jsp page.
- When i click on the button from this url host:port/example/menuBanner.jsp, am getting dialog box and the dialog box is at the page center.
- But when i try from this url host:port/example/customer.jsp, the dialog box is sticking at the page top and not getting the height of the box as well.
- My need is, when i try from this url too host:port/example/customer.jsp, i have to get the dialog box at the page center. i mean it should be at the top of customer.jsp page contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good that your iframe and page are on the same domain, it means you can call back and forth between parent/child in javascript.

I would recommend setting up a javascript function in your parent (customer.jsp)

```
function drawBox() {
  //handle drawing the box here however that has to happen
}
```

In the menuBanner.jsp update the button to trigger "parent.drawBox()"

```
onclick="parent.drawBox()"
```

Here is an example of this working:
http://mathforum.org/~amir/share/stack/outer.html

Comment: Can you say what isn't working about it?  Are you getting an error?  Try opening your browser's console, reload and click.  Anything reported?  I updated my answer with an example of this working.

Comment: I have the dialog box code in customer.jsp. and drawBox() script in utility.js page. and button in menuBanner.jsp. both jsp pages refers to utility.js. on click of the button, i gave onclick="parent.drawBox()".. and its working...

Comment: it exactly not the way what you said. some how i achieved it, after i saw your working example

Comment: Ok cool - you should feel free to answer your own question and accept that as the answer.